# Eloquent queries wrong table in many-to-many relationship

Tags: laravel-5.4, eloquent

I'm having trouble with a many-to-many relationshop. When querying the relationship (tested in tinker) I'm getting an error message triggered by sql  showing me a query on the wrong table.

My models:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Slideshow extends Model
{
    public function pictures ()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Picture::class);
    }
}

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Picture extends Model
{

    public function slideshows ()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Slideshow::class,'slideshowpictures')->withPivot('order')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

My migration for this relationship:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateSlideshowpicturesMigration extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up ()
    {
        $tablename = 'slideshowpictures';
        Schema::create($tablename, function (Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->integer('slideshow_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('picture_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('order')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        Schema::table($tablename, function ($table)
        {
            $table->foreign('slideshow_id')->references('id')->on('slideshows')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('picture_id')->references('id')->on('pictures')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down ()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('slideshowpictures');
    }
}
```

Now in tinker I get the following error:

```
>>> $slide =Slideshow::all()->first();
=> App\Slideshow {#751
     id: 1,
     name: "1",
     occasion_id: 1,
     created_at: "2017-09-16 19:01:59",
     updated_at: "2017-09-16 19:01:59",
   }
>>> $slide->pictures()->exists();
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pictures.slideshow_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select exists(select * from `pictures` where `pictures`.`slideshow_id` = 1 and `pictures`.`slideshow_id` is not null) as `exists`)'
>>> $slide->pictures();
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany {#830}
```

I could not yet find an answer and hope you can help me figure out why it is selecting from my pictures table and not the junction table which I created.

Comment: Please, post your migrations for `pictures` and `slides` tables so we can see if there is any mistake with your tables. But, I think your relations are wrong. The inverse of `belongsToMany` is `belongsToMany`, and the inverse of `hasMany` is `belongsTo`

Comment: After reading the docs again it is obvious and I just missed it. `belongsToMany` as the relation on both models is correct and I just used the wrong relation. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. It is there and I just missed it :(